# How to update Contact or Lead Salesforce object from CloudPage using AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, smart-capture

I have this piece of code. Upon adding this to the CloudPage, it break the page and show 500-Internal Server Error. According to me "UpdateSingleSalesforceObject" is causing this behavior.Can somebody please suggest a workaround for this.

```
%%[
SET @firstname = RequestParameter("FirstName")
SET @lastname = RequestParameter("LastName")
SET @email = RequestParameter("EmailAddress")
SET @company = RequestParameter("Company")
]%%


%%[
IF NOT EMPTY(@email) THEN
SET @lead = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id', 'Email', '=', @email)

IF RowCount(@lead) > 0 THEN
SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',Field(Row(@lead, 1),Id),First Name,@firstname,Last Name,@lastname,Company,@company)

ELSE
SET @result = CreateSalesforceObject('Lead', 3, 'First Name', @firstname, 'Last Name', @lastname, 'Email', @email, 'Company', @company)

ENDIF
ELSE
OUTPUT("Email must be provided in form")

ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no quotes around the field names in your update call.

That should be it. The rest looks fine at first glance.